# Query facebook events in a closed group with user_manage_groups permission returns empty data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This was done using the Graph API explorer. 
On facebook, there are clearly events in this group.

I used my access_token as a member of the group to query for the events in that group but I get empty data. I am also an admin in the group, hence, I have the user_manage_group permission.

This works fine on a public group but doesn't on a closed group it seems.

Comment: Can confirm via a quick test in Graph API Explorer, with `user_managed_groups` only I am not able to get the events of a group I am admin of. I get to see the events though, once I also grant `user_events` permission, so try that. (Also keep in mind that the docs say that by default only events within the last two weeks will be returned, you'd need to use since/until parameters to get events outside of that range that you might be able to see directly on Facebook.)

Comment: Thank you. Including the user_events permission works. Although this is limited to events in the group the user rsvp'd to